# Multiple Jquery plugins are not working simultaneously and affecting each others functionalities

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I am using two jquery plugins.When I add second Jquery plugin, the first stops working. There are two JS files and one script code in first plugin. And same in second plugin.

link for menu plugin I used is http://www.htmldrive.net/items/show/1020/multi-level-slide-accordion-menu-with-jQuery

link for search plugin ishttp://www.egrappler.com/searchMeme/index.htm

Check on link in my comment...search plugin is working fine in header but accordion menu plugin functionality disabled in body part and showing only top level menu(Home,JavaScript,Tutorials etc). Without search plugin this is working perfectly.

After adding search it get disabled.

Comment: Please include a minimal working demo in the question itself, and post links to the website/git of the plugins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A long shot:

try using [`jQuery.noConflict();`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/)

```
<script src="other_lib.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
    $.noConflict();
    // Code that uses other library's $ can follow here.
</script>
```

Comment: Where I have to add this $.noConflict() ?? In all JS files and script tags?? Actually m totally a newbie to jquery

Comment: In the head of your page that is using multiple JS libraries. Please Read the linked official documentation

Comment: Thanks a lot...It worked ..this was getting onto my nerves...Thanks a lot for ur help.

Comment: @Andrea..one more question here..for more than 2 plugins..how we gonna remove conflicts??

Comment: A plugin should be designed to avoid conflicts: if it's not, either change plugin's code, or change plugin :> But if it works good, just keep them with noConflict()